# Avoiding multiple rebases in large git projects

Tags: git, github

In git repositories with large number of developers, it is very likely that when I want to merge a pull request, I find that some other coworkers have already merged a new pull request. Then I have to rebase, probably solve some merge conflicts, and probably have to make some more changes to adapt the feature just merged, run the tests again, ...etc and eventually try to merge my PR again.

By then, I can find another coworker with a new merged PR again, and the same cycle again .. so how to break this time-wasting loop ?

Comment: One probable way to do it would by _dropping the requirement to rebase_. Rebasing is fine, don't get me wrong.... and necessary sometimes... but it should _not_ be a must... if you ask me, at least.

Comment: "Then I have to rebase" Why? The usual thing is reverse merge, not rebase. If you rebase you'll have to force push an existing pull request, which is bad. — Even so, yes, this is a common situation; you are always in a race condition, because you are collaborating with others. If you can't change the work situation, you'll just have to suck it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long-lasting pull request, where it's taking a long time to deal with and the likelihood of complications such as merge conflicts and rewrites is increasing, then the best strategy, in my view is this:

1. *Reverse merge* (not rebase) to keep your PR branch up to date with the main branch.
2. Do it *often* — at least once a day.

This will greatly reduce the amount of work you have to do when the time comes to merge your PR branch.